# How does printf display a string from a char*?

Tags: c++, pointers, char

Consider a simple example

```
Eg: const char* letter = "hi how r u";
```

letter is a const character pointer, which points to the string "hi how r u". Now when i want to print the data or to access the data I should use `*letter` correct?

But in this situation, shouldn't I only have to use the address in the call to printf?

```
printf("%s",letter);
```

So why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*letter` is actually a character; it's the first character that `letter` points to. If you're operating on a whole string of characters, then *by convention*, functions will look at that character, and the next one, etc, until they see a zero ('\0') byte.

In general, if you have a pointer to a bunch of elements (i.e., an array), then the pointer points to the first element, and somehow any code operating on that bunch of elements needs to know how many there are. For `char*`, there's the zero convention; for other kinds of arrays, you often have to pass the length as another parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because printf has a signature like this: `int printf(const char* format, ...);` which means it is expecting pointer(s) to a char table, which it will internally dereference.

Comment: OK, the type of the variadic arguments isn't evident from the signature, but the point is that internally it's expected to be a char *, not char.

Answer (score 1):

letter does not point to the string as a whole, but to the first character of the string, hence a char pointer.

When you dereference the pointer (with `*`) then you are referring to the first character of the string.

however a single character is much use to prinf (when print a string) so it instead takes the pointer to the first element and increments it's value printing out the dereference values until the null character is found '\0'.

As this is a C++ question it is also important to note that you should really store strings as the safe encapulated type `std::string` and you the type safe iostreams where possible:

```
std::string line="hi how r u";
std::cout << line << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

`%s` prints up to the first `\0` see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx, `%s` is a character string format field, there is nothing strange going on here.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%s")` expect the address in order to go through the memory searching for `NULL` (`\0`) = end of string. In this case you say only `letter`. To `printf("%c")` would expect the value not the address: `printf("%c", *letter);`

Answer (score 1):

`printf` takes pointers to data arrays as arguments. So, if you're displaying a string (a type of array) with `%s` or a number with `%d`, `%e`, `%f`, etc, always pass the variable name without the `*`. The variable name *is* the pointer to the first element of the array, and `printf` will print each element of the array by using simple pointer arithmetic according to the type (`char` is 1 or 2 bytes, `int`s are 4, etc) until it reaches an EOL or zero value.

Of course, if you make a pointer *to* the array variable, then you'd want to dereference that pointer with `*`. But that's more the exception than the rule. :)